# Magento2.3.3 - Where can I see the Store Credit amount of an user?

Tags: magento2.3.3, creditmemo, magento-community, store-credit

I'm using `Magento2.3` Open Source. [Here in the doc](https://docs.magento.com/m2/ce/user_guide/sales/credit-memo-create.html), you can see references to Store Credit in the Open Source version:

> If the purchase was paid with store credit, mark the Refund to Store
>   Credit checkbox to credit the amount to the customer account balance.

Comment: As I know store credit features available only in the enterprise edition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation you are referencing is for credit memos, you'll see in that same doc the definition of a credit memo:

> A credit memo is a document that shows the amount that is due the customer for a full or partial refund.

This is different than store credit which is only available in Magento Commerce edition, not open source

**Update**

I see the line you referenced now. I suspect that has just found its way into the the Open Source documentation erroneously. Store credit definitely isn't a feature of Magento Open Source.